# Can't seem to find an open port to host a webserver

Tags: apache-http-server, internet-connection, port-forwarding, webserver

It appears that my ISP is blocking every single port as i cannot seem to find a port that isn't blocked except for 22 (SSH). I can't find a port to host my home webserver on (which i am trying to set up for the first time).

What are my options for setting up a webserver if i just can't seem to get through? Are there any ports that i should try that i may not have (i tried, 80, 81, 8080, and 443).

My apache webserver doesn't even show up locally! I may not have it configured correctly but i swear it is! Do you think this is a separate issue (AKA i am dumb and didn't set up apache correctly).

Comment: If it doesn't show up locally, then the problem isn't with your ISP. What operating system are you running Apache on? Do the logs say it started up successfully? What happens when you try to access it locally? (And are you behind NAT? If so, are you trying to access it by the local IP address or the public IP address?)

Comment: Or is your firewall on? On either computer?